# Fail to get the total number of posts

Tags: functions, statistics

I would like to get the total number of posts by the following code:

```
<?php 
     $published_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;
     echo 'Total posts: '; $published_posts;  
?>
```

The result is `Total posts:` without followed by a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic PHP string concatenation

```
echo 'Total posts: '; $published_posts;
```

Should be

```
echo 'Total posts: ' . $published_posts;
```

Comment: However, it works while using `<?php echo 'Total views: '; get_totalviews(); ?>`. Can you tell the difference?

Comment: Most probably `get_totalview()` echo's its output :-)